# Check if a script has run atleast once before

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way to see if any PowerShell script has executed at-least once before, without the script itself creating any logs? I.e. is there some sort of a native record keeping mechanism for already executed scripts (an example would be an event generating and hence creating an event log), meaning a log of the script actually executed was made at runtime but externally?

For example : If script A was executed once today, check during the second execution (say 2 days later) of script A if it had already executed before.

Can this be done through any Event logs, or through environment variables?

EDIT: Please note, for this particular script, no text files or logs can be made. Is there a way to do this without actually leaving a trace "physically" but instead relying on any parameters being set when a script executes?

EDIT2: This script would be executing with the least of privileges, so not only an account which does not have admin permissions, but would also not have approved permissions to create text or log files.

Comment: You could have ScriptA write a small text file with a 'LastRunDate' in it. Then have it check if that file exists and if so, when. Instead of a text file, the registry could also be an option to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, one constraint is the creation of logs for this script, i.e. the script cannot create any text files, or logs in the machine.

Comment: So, can you write to the registry then?

Comment: That would count as a log as well, so no.

This script would be executing with the least of privileges, so not only an account which does not have admin permissions, but would also not have approved permissions to create text or log files.

Comment: You can't simultanously insist on _not recording the execution of a script_ and then expect to confidently detect previous executions. It's a bit like saying "Forget this piece of information, but make sure you remember it!" :) If you can spin up an external web service of database that you can track executions with then it's a different question.

Comment: That is the question though. If there is no native record keeping mechanism system-wide for a PowerShell script, then that's fine, onto fighting with the boss then :)

Comment: `Taskmon` can be used to fetch and monitor scripts execution

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The second execution of script A could be at a different time.

Comment: @Vish PowerShell has that - ScriptBlock Execution Logging - but depending on log size and rollover settings, if the last execution was some time ago it might not be available locally any more. If you have a SIEM or other log forwarding solution you can turn on logging, forward it, and then build a service on top of that data that can say "yes/no" to whether a certain script has ever been executed on System X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about self-modifying code? It's technically cheating, as the change is being done in the script file itself. No external logging is done, though.

```
write-host -nonewline "Script has started"
$src = get-content $MyInvocation.MyCommand
$header = $src[0]
if($header -notmatch "^#") {
  write-host " ...first time!" 
  $newScript = @()
  $newScript += "#"
  $newScript += $src
  set-content $MyInvocation.MyCommand $newScript
} else { write-host " ...nth time!" }
```

The script reads its own contents. If the first line doesn't start with a hash, it's the first invokation. The script then creates a new set of source code. The first line is a hash, original source comes after that. Then the original script is overwritten.

As a side note, the requirement to log-but-not-log is self-contradictory just as @Mathias R. Jessen pointed out. There is, however, [process tracking audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-process-tracking) available in Windows. Also, there is [script block logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/wmf/whats-new/script-logging?view=powershell-7). In theory (and with proper permissions), one might search the Windows' event logs for previous run attempts.

I'd much rather pop the why stack and find out the underlying reason, as the requirement to eat and keep a cacke sounds very much like an XY problem.

Comment: I understand stackoverflow is not a forum to discuss what-ifs and environmental constraints. Finding out the solution to this particular problem would be my own prerogative seeing that there are environment specific issues. Marked as correct.